# How to port forward to enable NAT type on Playstation

Tags: networking, port-forwarding

OK, so I use my Ubuntu laptop as a WiFi hotspot for the PS4 to connect to the internet. I had to use VPN (because our crappy telecom is a government owned monopoly, many blocked sites, etc.), which works fine.
Problem is, NAT type fails during connection test and so I cannot play games like Dark Souls 3 and Bloodborne online, although I can connect to and download stuff from the PSN. I did some online search and discovered that I have to assign a static ip address and do some port forwarding.
My question is, how do I do port forwarding on my computer (which I assume has sort of taken the role of router here)? I believe that this can be solved, just need a little technical help. Networking was never my strong suit :-).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add iptables rules to the forward table in your ubuntu installation. Here is a NAT HOWTO on iptables. http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/NAT-HOWTO.txt

Comment: Thanks for answering. Took a look at the link you provided, and it's still a bit too complicated I'm afraid. Can you provide a simpler set of instructions? I know the IP address assigned to the PS4, the default gateway and the required port.